# aggregate functions select

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

There is a tbl_Regist table:

```
| ID | CODE   | VAL       |
+----+--------+-----------+
| 95 | numVz  | 06        |
| 95 | prevVz | 84605898  |
| 95 | ndatVz | 10.10.10  |
| 95 | numVz  | 06        |
| 95 | prevVz | 14666641  |
| 95 | ndatVz | 11.11.11  |
| 95 | numVz  | 06        |
| 95 | prevVz | 84605898  |
| 95 | ndatVz | 12.12.12  |
```

I need to get the data in this view:

```
| ID | numVz | prevVz   | ndatVz   | 
+----|-------+----------+----------+
| 95 | 06    | 84605898 | 10.10.10 |   
| 95 | 06    | 14666641 | 11.11.11 |
| 95 | 06    | 84605898 | 12.12.12 |
```

My request:

```
select 
      t.ID,
      max(case when t.code = 'numVz'  then t.val end) as numVz
     ,max(case when t.code = 'prevVz' then t.val end) as prevVz
     ,max(case when t.code = 'ndatVz' then t.val end) as ndatVz
from tbl_Regist t
where t.ID = 95
group by t.ID     


| ID | numVz | prevVz   | ndatVz   | 
+----|-------+----------+----------+
| 95 | 06    | 84605898 | 12.12.12 |
```

Returns only one row, If you remove the aggregate function, it returns 9 rows

Comment: SQL tables represent UNORDERED sets.  Your results seem based on the ordering of the data.  You need a column that specifies the ordering.

Comment: With his data handled like that you will have a lot more difficult problems than writing just that one query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `row_number()` to add an enumeration.  However, you really want an ordering column:

```
select r.ID,
       max(case when r.code = 'numVz'  then r.val end) as numVz,
       max(case when r.code = 'prevVz' then r.val end) as prevVz,
       max(case when r.code = 'ndatVz' then r.val end) as ndatVz
from (select r.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id, code order by <ordering column>) as seqnum
      from tbl_Regist r
     ) r
where r.ID = 95
group by r.ID, seqnum;
```